# Notification boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I create notification boxes like these in CSS:

[image]
[image]

I tried to use https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_notes.asp but this doesn't even look closely like this.

Comment: consider writing your own code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add block and it will look very similar to w3 school example.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
}

.danger {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  border-left: 6px solid #f44336;
}

.success {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  border-left: 6px solid #4CAF50;
}

.info {
  background-color: #e7f3fe;
  border-left: 6px solid #2196F3;
}


.warning {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  border-left: 6px solid #ffeb3b;
}

.danger1{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="danger">
  <p><span class="danger1"><strong>Danger!</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apparently they are called bootstrap alerts, an example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: Yes. But your cquestion didnt mention bootstrap. I thought you trying to do this on pure css. Thats why I created solution for you. You could add span tag and add class d-block it should work or you can do that class in css with display block